# Checking for consecutiveness of values in Rust

Tags: rust

I am currently implementing a poker game and I have encountered an issue that sounds really simple; it may be so, but I can't think of an idiomatic solution: how do I check if a hand is a straight?

A straight is when all the ranks of the cards in a hand (i.e. 5 cards) are consecutive, e.g. Two, Three, Four, Five, Six. The suit can be disregarded (otherwise this would be a check for a straight flush).

Consider the following code:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Eq, Ord)]
enum Rank {
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King,
    Ace
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq)]
enum Suit {
    Spades,
    Clubs,
    Diamonds,
    Hearts
}

#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct Card {
    rank: Rank,
    suit: Suit
}

struct Hand(Vec<Card>);

impl Hand {
    fn is_straight(&self) -> bool {
        // this should be easy
    }
}
```

The point is not iterating over an `enum` - I know this currently can't be done in Rust. I am not sure how to implement this if `Rank`s were an array or a `Vec<Rank>` (can be already sorted). The issue is checking if the `Hand`'s `Rank`s are consecutive (like `succ` or `pred` in Haskell).

Any ideas how to do it idiomatically in *vanilla* Rust? The best I have come up with is checking if a sorted array of all `Rank`s contains the sorted array of `Hand`'s `Ranks`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give enum variants values (C-like) and easily compare them that way:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Eq, Ord)]
enum Rank {
    Two=2,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King,
    Ace
}

impl Rank {
    // Passing by value as Rank: Copy
    pub fn next_is(self, other: Rank) -> bool {
        ((self as i32) + 1) == (other as i32)
    }
}
```

Then `is_straight` is simple to implement using the `next_is` method.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a hack with assigning numeric values, but I didn't know it was possible to do it in such a concise way (I thought I would need an ```impl``` assigning values). Let's hope Rust implements a ```Trait``` like  Haskell's ```Enum``` in the future (there is already an RFC for that - https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/284).

Answer (score 4):

As Chris Emerson already said, you can assign integer values to enum variants and then cast it via the `as` operator. So we have:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Eq, Ord)]
enum Rank {
    Two = 2,
    Three,
    Four,
    // ...
}
```

The method `is_straight()` can be implemented using iterator magic:

```
fn is_straight(&self) -> bool {
    self.0
        .iter()
        .map(|c| c.rank as i8 - self.0[0].rank as i8)
        .eq(0..5)
}
```

The unchecked indexing `self.0[0]` is safe, because the closure in `map()` is only called when at least one element is within the vector. And it [seems to work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9cb5a7fa9d685d86b82fe9378a060f43&version=stable&backtrace=0) (I removed the `Suit` to reduce noise).